# Floating embed iframe Chrome app - The "app.window.alwaysOnTop" permission is required

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

MANIFEST

```
{
    "name": "EMBED",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "app" : {
        "background": {
            "scripts":  ["background.js"]
        },
        "permissions": [
            "app.window.alwaysOnTop"
          ]
    }
}
```

BACKGROUND.JS

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('embed.html', {      
      alwaysOnTop: true,
      id: 'mainWindow',
      frame: 'none',
      state: "normal",
      hidden: false,
      resizable: false,
    });
  });
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
      <h1>hello</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error i am getting :

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running app.window.create: The "app.window.alwaysOnTop" permission is required.
    at chrome-extension://fphjeingehfcjbabfanfbaifmhegaoic/background.js:52:23
```

So it's asking me to put a permission exactly after chrome.app.window.(permission should go here).create

I tried `permissions: ["tabs", "alwaysOnTop", "window.app.alwaysOnTop"]`.

Note: In html i want to embed an iframe in near future. So if there is anything else that i need to adjust, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, would you be so kind explaining a bit more on what are you trying to achieve, give a little more background? It's hard to grasp at the moment.

Comment: I am trying to create a chrome extension / app which on click creates an always on top window and inside that window is an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was inside the manifest file. I put "permissions" inside of the "app" object.

WRONG

```
{
    "name": "EMBED",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "app" : {
        "background": {
            "scripts":  ["background.js"]
        },
        "permissions": [
            "app.window.alwaysOnTop"
          ]
    }
}
```

CORRECT

```
{
    "name": "EMBED",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "app" : {
        "background": {
            "scripts":  ["background.js"]
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "alwaysOnTopWindows"
      ]
}
```